# Populate text area with string

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to populate a certain text area with a string in java script.  I have defined the string as the variable "result" in my function and said for the function to return the variable result.  When it returns "result" I want it to be returned in a specific text area. So I called the text area by using document.getElementByID but it wont populate the text area.  I am unsure where where I went wrong or where to go from here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have included the code for the form and function below.

**JavaScript**

```
function newVerse(form1) {
    var objects = form1.objects.value;
    var destination = form1.destination.value;
    var result = "Where have all the" + objects + "gone?" + "Long time passing." + "Where have all the" + objects + "gone?" + "Long time ago." + "Where have all the" + objects + "gone?" + "Gone to" + destination + ", everyone." + "When will they ever learn?" + "When will they ever learn?";
    document.getElementByID(textarea).value += result
    return result;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name=form1>Objects:
    <input type="text" name="objects">
    <br>Destination:
    <input type="text" name="destination">
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="newVerse(form1)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xvMPR/1/).

Here are you errors:

### Javascript

```
function newVerse(form1) { 
  var objects = form1.objects.value;
  var destination = form1.destination.value;
  var result = "Where have all the" + objects + "gone?" + "Long time passing." + "Where have all the" + objects + "gone?" + "Long time ago." + "Where have all the" + objects + "gone?" + "Gone to" + destination + ", everyone." + "When will they ever learn?" + "When will they ever learn?";

  //Missing quotes arround text area.
  //Missing ; althought is not necessary.
  //document.getElementByID(textarea).value += result
   document.getElementByID('textarea').value += result;
}
```

### HTML

```
<form name=form1><!-- Missing "" around form1 -->
  Objects:
  <input type="text" name="objects"> <!-- Missing closing / -->
  <br>Destination:
  <input type="text" name="destination"> <!-- Missing closing / -->
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="newVerse(form1)">
  <!-- You want to pass the actual form, so replace onclick="newVerse(form1)" by onclick="newVerse(document.forms['form1'])"-->
  <!-- Missing closing / -->
</form>
```